# Frontpage overriding my posts

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, homepage, frontpage, table

Each time i make a new post I cant see it ok my website when I view it. The front page (which is blank) seems to override my posts. How do I remove it or change the settings

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have an error (php or js) on your front page. In order to elaborate on the situation, you have to check the following things:

0. Go to your home page and check any issues the [Chrome Debugger Tool](https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse154/19su/resources/assets/debugging/chrome-inspector.html). Check the console tag specifically. Hope you might see something suspicious there.
1. Check the front page template, Settings->Reading->[Home page displays](https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/settings-reading-screen/) You can turn the selected page on or off and check any changes.
2. Enable [`wp_debug`](https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/debugging-in-wordpress/) mode on your `wp-config.php` file to see any issues on your site.
3. Enable [PHP error log](https://wordpress.com/go/tutorials/set-up-wordpress-error-logs/) on your site and check log details.
4. I hope one of the above steps could tell you something, but If you don't see any clue along the way, it might be an infinite loop in your php.